# SVG Text and Rect position

Tags: svg, position

I have this code:

```
<g pointer-events="default">
    <g>
        <g x="0" y="0" width="145" height="47" regroup="false">
            <text x="0" y="0">
                <tspan x="0" y="0">some text</tspan>
            </text>
        </g>
        <g x="0" y="0" width="80" height="60" regroup="false">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="80" height="60" fill="white" />
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

There is one css rule `box-sizing: border-box;`which is apply to all elements.

It produce that:

[image]

The grid is coming from a sliding element from the first `<g>`.

I don't understand why the text element and the rect are not displayed at the same `y`.
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: box-sizing has no effect on SVG elements. I'm not sure what you're asking. The origin for text is the bottom right hand corner by default is that not what you expected/wanted?

Comment: The `<rect>` starts at the right position. Since `<rect>` and `<text>` have the same `x` and `y` I would expect that the start at the right position. Text is start a bit above the image. My question is: why and how can I make both element start at the same position.

Comment: Yes but the origin for a rect element is top left, whereas text is bottom left. Where exactly do you want the text displayed. Just adjust the y till it's there is the easiest answer.

Comment: I don't want to adjust it because if it's bottom left, it's depends on the font size and number of line.

Comment: I think you want dominant-baseline="hanging" then.